# What exception guarantees do gcc atomic builtins offer?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, atomic, built-in

I cannot find documentation which states what exception guarantees (none, basic, strong, nothrow) the gcc atomic builtins (e.g. __sync_synchronize()) offer. Can anyone provide details on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since they are usable in C, which does not have exceptions, none of them will throw.